# Drag and drop gtk textview

Tags: python, gtk

I would like to know if i can stop gtk textview from writing the data after a drop event.

I have connected `drag-data-recieved` signal but I can't stop the textview from writing the data even if it returns true.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning True on `drag-drop`. The [docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-drag-drop). The `drag-data-recieved` is for specialized drag-drop data, not for general drag-drop.

Comment: If I return true on `drag-drop` how can I get the data from the drop